# WhatsApp notifications - Notification Bar - J3

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger

Samsung J3 - Android 5.1.1 (Lollipop)
Regarding WhatsApp notifications....On my previous phone (Samsung Galaxy Trend) When a new WhatsApp message comes through....

1. The phone vibrates
2. A number "1" shows up on the WhatsApp icon
3. The little WhatsApp icon shows up in the top left hand corner of the phone.

This configuration is exactly how I wanted it...

I seem to be having some trouble replicating this exact configuration on my new phone (J3).

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: Nope - I don't mind the message count.
Basically, I don't want to see a preview of the message on the screen

Comment: What settings do you have in WhatsApp> Settings > Notifications?